# Objects exposed on JSON web-api - how to stop the property names changing case?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an object model that looks like:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I'm populating this via Dapper, and exposing it to an angular.js consumer, but the property names in the JSON are coming out as:

```
{
     "productCode": 1,
     "productInfo": "Product number 1"
}
```

Note in particular the camel-case. I would like it to match the original declared names, i.e.

```
{
     "ProductCode": 1,
     "ProductInfo": "Product number 1"
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What don't you want happening, are your msising the quotes from the output json, don't you like the casing?

Comment: wait... Dapper does ADO.NET, not JSON... are you sure you're talking about the right tool? what code are you running to get this JSON result?

Comment: I don't want the ProductCode  to become productCode on my json result. I want it to stay the same.@nikneem

Comment: @MarcGravell I am consuming the API with angular

Comment: that has nothing whatsoever to do with Dapper... Dapper is only involved in the SQL => objects bit; so: presumably you are exposing some kind of web-API that angular is consuming? What is that web API? Is it ASP.NET MVC, for example? You need to tell *that* what serialization rules you want. Most likely, it is using JSON.Net, so adding `[JsonProperty("ProductCode")]` above `ProductCode` should fix it. Nothing to do with Dapper, though

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks that solved it.

Comment: @Whatives k; I'm going to edit the question a bit, just so it can be useful for anyone searching in the future...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the hood, it is most likely that the web-API is using JSON.Net as the JSON serialization engine; this means that you can control the output using JSON.Net's attributes, for example:

```cs
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("ProductCode")]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ProductInfo")]
    public string ProductInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Without these, JSON.Net uses conventions and configuration - and the usual JSON convention *is* to use camel-case, hence that is the default. You *can* also probably change the default configuration, but I would advise against that unless you understand the scope of the impact.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to preserve property names case from changing for Newtonsoft.Json serializer:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options=>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() {  };
});
```

or for System.Text.Json:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```