# Disable Newtonsoft changing JSON case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a document which has a field:

```
{
   FOB: "..."
}
```

However when I return it:

```
    [HttpGet("{documentRef}")]
    public ActionResult<Ten> Get(string documentRef)
    {
        var data = _service.FindOneTen(documentRef);
        if (data != null) return data;
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return NotFound();
    }
```

It is converted to this:

```
{
    fob: "..."
}
```

**How can I stop this happening / Why is this happening?**

I've seen examples of people using

```
PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
```

To disable it for MVC / the normal JSON which I tried and didn't work.

**Startup:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    }
```

**Edit**

While [Objects exposed on JSON web-api - how to stop the property names changing case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590778/objects-exposed-on-json-web-api-how-to-stop-the-property-names-changing-case?noredirect=1&lq=1) is solving the problem in one way, I would rather not need to specify for every field in the model.

Comment: _"I have a document"_ - what kind of "document"? MongoDB? What does the `Ten` class look like? Read [ask] and provide all relevant details.

Comment: can you specify, which convention would you like to use? you want to avoid the camelCase convention or use your own convention name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options=>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() {  };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: @Jack i updated my answer and it worked successfully

Comment: This is working and better than the one marked duplicate as it actually answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .net core. You can try use default .net core serializer, it should preserve the original casing.

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize()
```

And also, you need to config in Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

If you need to use Json.net then use this

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
{
o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
});
```

Comment: I need to use Newton as I require it to serialize some JObjects.

Comment: @Jack, I just added solution for Newtonsoft (Json.net)

Comment: Please don't copy the answers!